# AngularJS: Unsubscribe Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, listener, broadcast

In one of my controllers, there is a directive `<div keypress-events>` that subscribes to pressed keys:

```
directives.directive('keypressEvents', ['$document', '$rootScope',  function ($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function () {
            $document.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

There is also a listener that performs pagination when a users pressed any arrow  keys.

```
var listener = $scope.$on('keypress', function (e, a, key) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.key = key;

        if (key == 39) {
            $scope.currentPage = Math.min($scope.currentPage + 1, $scope.numPages)
        } else if (key == 37) {
            $scope.currentPage = Math.max($scope.currentPage - 1, 1)
        }
    });
})
```

However, when you navigate to another controller and then go back, the listener will be called twice. So how can I unsubscribe to that event?

I tried only to destroy the listener, but this does not work...

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  listener(); // remove listener.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `keydown` event from directive gets bounded twice when you revisit the page. What you could do is, before moving away from page take care of removing 
`keydown` event of directive, for the same place hook on `$destroy` event of `scope`.

**Code**

```
directives.directive('keypressEvents', ['$document', '$rootScope',  function ($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            var event =  function (e) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
            };
            $document.on('c', event);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function (){
                angular.element($document).off('keydown', event);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

> **Note**: As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was
>   superseded by the [**`.off()`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was
>   already discouraged.

Comment: I would encourage usage of on/off instead of bind/unbind because  as of jQuery 3.0 and angularJs's jqLite 1.6.0, .bind() has been deprecated.

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa thanks for mention, I added it as note ;)